# Fake Generation failing for Odata v4 client

Tags: c#, .net, odata, microsoft-fakes

When I try to generate fakes for Microsoft.OData.Client.dll, I am getting the following error. Has anyone faced this issue and is there any resolution for this?

> metadata : Method 'get_Url' in type 'Microsoft.OData.Client.InternalODataRequestMessage' from assembly 'Microsoft.OData.Client, Version=6.8.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation. (TaskId:18)
>   1>    metadata : Method 'get_Url' in type 'RequestMessageWithCachedStream' from assembly 'Microsoft.OData.Client, Version=6.8.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation. (TaskId:18)
>   1>    metadata : Method 'get_Url' in type 'Microsoft.OData.Client.HttpWebRequestMessage' from assembly 'Microsoft.OData.Client, Version=6.8.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation. (TaskId:18)
>   1>    metadata : failed to load assembly Microsoft.OData.Client: (TaskId:18)
>   1>    metadata : Method 'get_Url' in type 'Microsoft.OData.Client.HttpWebRequestMessage' from assembly 'Microsoft.OData.Client, Version=6.8.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation. (TaskId:18)

Answer (score 1):

I'm a teammate of Alok, and we eventually figured out the answer thanks to help from the OData Client V4 team. This is similar to other answers about dealing with the PCL, but might be a bit more useful.

The trick when having this problem (or any others like it) is to do the following on the type that you're having the problem with:

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(Uri).Assembly.Location);
Console.WriteLine(typeof(Uri).Assembly.FullName);
```

Use this information to then put into the Fakes Assembly generator. This is the specific assembly that was being referenced which we needed:

```
<Reference Path="C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll" FullName="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
```

Once you do that you should be able to compile the fake.

This should work for any kind of problem like the one [referenced here at stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22271705/unable-to-generate-fakes-for-an-assembly-referencing-a-portable-class-library).